# How can I calculate sub-aggregates with azure search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

In azure search I have documents with the following format which comes from IoT realm:

```
device identifier: string
event_level: int
```

I'd like to facet(group) the count by device identifier and  event level together.  I can do basic facet at each individual level, but can't figure out multiple fields.  Basically I'm looking for a count of the different `event_level` per `device_identifier`.  So result would be

```
device_identifier 1 - event_level 2 - count 100
device_identifier 1 - event_level 1 - count 00
...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `device_identifier` and `event_level` into a single field and facet on that. However, be aware that faceting on fields with high cardinality can be slow.